# how can i change app content discription on my google play console , after publishing my app?

Tags: facebook, google-play, ssl-certificate, google-play-games, google-play-console

i recently publish my game in play store and every thing was fine , but i want to change my privacy policy URL now( because it did not have SSL certification and now i changed my website address and its safe now ).
i opened play console and simply changed the URL address in app content hours ago but , it seems nothing changed when i click on privacy policy link below my game page on play store and it still redirect me to the old privacy policy.
i really need to change the privacy policy URL to new one because it cause me a problem in Facebook.
help please...

Answer (score 0):

If you made the change from the Console and you can still see it, wait a few hours, sometimes 1/2 days, it will be then visible to everyone. Changes are not instantly applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can change app content description on Google Play Console **New UI August 2020** by this way

Store presence -> Main store listing -> Full Description -> Save

Then, wait for your changes to be accepted.

[image]